# How to solve: y'' + 9y = sin(3t)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

I need to find the particular solution to the equation:
$$y'' + 9y = \sin(3t)$$
I thought we were looking for a trigonometric forcing term on the form:
$$y = a\cdot\cos(3t) + b\cdot\sin(3t)$$

But this gave me zero.

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you solve it with a Laplace transform? And are there initial conditions?

Comment: @graydad I don't know, I've never done that.

Comment: You want a particular solution of the form $y= t(a\cos(3t)+b\sin(3t))$.

Comment: See the extra $t$ in Jessica's suggestion?  Your DE textbook should explain about that when it does the method of undetermined coefficients.

Comment: $$r^2+9r=0 \to r(r+9)=0 \to r_1=0   ,r_2=-9$$

$$y=1+e^{-9t}+A$$

where $A=asin(3t)+bcos(3t)$   find A' and A'', plug into original and solve for A.  Is this correct?

Comment: Woops...that is 9y and not 9'y - my first comment is wrong because the characteristic equation is wrong. The method still works just solve $r^2+9=0$ It will give complex roots I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we consider the characteristic equation :
$$
x^2+9=0
$$
this equation has two complex roots which are $3i$ and $-3i$.

Then the general solution read
$$
y(t)=A \exp(3it)+ B \exp(-3it)
$$
But because of the nonhomogeneous term, you have to add an additionnal term, and the solution read :
$$
y(t)=(A +C t)\exp(3it)+ (B +D t)\exp(-3it)
$$
this is a complex solution, ina simple way we have something like:
$$
y(t)=(A +C t)\sin(3t)+ (B +D t)\cos(3t)
$$