# How to solve the $u'' + u + \sin (x) = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

Could someone help me to obtain the general solution to this differential equation?

I need to solve the DE: $$u'' + u + \sin (x) = 0$$

---

Note: "I got as far as the general solution for $\;u''+u=0,$ but it was the $\;\sin(x)$ term that confused me."

Comment: Which method would you like to solve it with: Undetermined Coefficients, Variation of Parameters, Laplace Transforms etc.. ?

Comment: I believe it has complex roots, having a solution of the form $Ae^xcosx + Be^{-x}sinx $ but ive had some issues with the fact theres a sinx in the DE.

Comment: I guessed as much, I wasnt convinced with it. Hence why I seek guidance.

Comment: The general solution is $$\left(\frac{x}{2}+A\right)\cos(x)+B\sin(x).$$ I suggest to study the topic a bit more. I cannot believe your book/course has not covered such differential equations.

Comment: Using [undetermined coefficients](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx), guess a particular solution in the form $x(A\cos{x}+B\sin{x})$ and solve for $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Look at this [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121902/how-to-solve-y-9y-sin3t?rq=1)  I refer to duplicate, because it has the same form: $$y'' + 9y = \sin(3t) \iff y'' n+ 9y -\sin(3t) = 0$$

Comment: My apologies, theres been a lot of responses and a lot of people were editing or deleting. I am grateful for the interest. Ive been playing around with what I have recieved. I got as far as the general solution for y''+y=0 but it was the sin x term that confused me. Im currently looking at the answer below and trying to understand. sorry for the lack of reponse from me

Comment: Thanks for your response.  In the question about the question I refer to above, the right-hand side should be $y'' + 9y - \sin(3t)$.   Any way, I posted it so you have a link to another similar problem, and the answers provided there.

Comment: I know see you provided a link. Thank you, I will check it out!

Comment: @Clovers Have you been taught [Variation of Parameters](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx) before? Using that method, you can derive the particular solution without the use of an ansatz.

Comment: One more helpful link [How to solve $y'' + y = -2\sin x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873463/how-to-solve-y-y-2-sinx?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the 2nd order ODE with constant coefficients, which is linear. Hence, general solution comes from solving the homogeneous ODE $$u''+u=0$$ which you can do by substituting $u = e^{rx}$, which yields the equation $r^2+1=0$. You get $r = \pm i$ and hence
$$
u_h(x) = \alpha e^{ix} + \beta e^{-ix} = a \sin x + b \cos x
$$
is the general solution. To pick the particular solution for your free term, let
$$
u_p(x) = Ax \sin x + B x \cos x
$$
and note that 
$$
\begin{split}
u_p'(x) &= A\sin x + Ax \cos x + B \cos x - Bx \sin x \\
        &= (A-Bx) \sin x + (Ax+B) \cos x.
\end{split}
$$
Similarly,
$$
\begin{split}
u_p''(x) &= -B\sin x + (A-Bx) \cos x + A \cos x - (Ax+B) \sin x \\
         &= (-Ax-2B) \sin x + (2A-Bx) \cos x.
\end{split}
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{split}
0 = u_p(x) + u_p''(x) + \sin x = (1-2B) \sin x + 2A \cos x.
\end{split}
$$
which implies $B = 1/2$ and $A = 0$, so $u_p(x) = x \cos (x) /2$ and hence the general solution would be
$$
u(x) = u_p(x) + u_h(x) = a \sin x + \left(b + \frac{x}{2} \right) \cos x
$$

Comment: How about the $\sin x$ term?

Comment: @HenningMakholm he only asked for general solution. That term will introduce $Ax \sin x + Bx \cos x$ into the particular solution, but the OP never asked for that

Comment: I think you are confusing *general solution* with *complementary solution*. The general solution includes the particular solution.

Comment: @projectilemotion fixed, term confusion... they called it *general* and *particular* solutions  in my ODE class...

Comment: @projectilemotion fixed

Comment: @amWhy sorry, forgot to delete in the last revision, doing it now

Comment: @no problem... I've done the same thing a couple of times...Moving from hint to answer, but forgetting to "unhint" it!